# How to track changes of a referenced element with React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a problem which requires me to store the texted of a referenced element in an array.
Now, I first want to display the text for each element(paragraph element with "ebookName" class) in the console, before storing it in the array.
But I have been having problems... Whenever I click an element, the console just logs the previous elements text always. I want for each paragraph element to log that specific elements text, not the previous one

Link to JS code:

```
import React from 'react'
import "./Styles/Ebook.css"
import { useRef } from 'react';

function Ebook() {
    const bookName = useRef();

    let ebookData = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("ebook"));

    /*function that displays the specific text of a specific element onto the console*/
    const elementLogFunction = () =>{
        console.log(bookName.current)
    }


    return (
        <section id="musicRender">
           {ebookData.results.map((ebook, i)=>{
               return (
               <div key={i} className='ebookContentContainer'>
                   <div className="ebookPicture">
                   <img src={ebook.artworkUrl100} alt={ebook.trackName} />
                   </div>
                   
                   <div className="ebook-description">
                       <p className="ebookAuthor">Author: {ebook.artistName}</p>
                       <p ref={bookName} className='ebookAName'>Book Name: {ebook.trackName}</p>
                       <p className="price">Price: R{(ebook.price * 15.36).toFixed(0)}</p>
                   <button onClick={elementLogFunction} className="favourites-btn">Add To Favourites</button>
                   </div>
               </div>)
            })}
        </section>
    )
  }

export default Ebook
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, `ref` is only referred to the same data, and the new one will override the old one. In your case, the last book data will be kept.

If you want to have individual book data separately, you can pass a param to `elementLogFunction`.

You also shouldn't read `sessionStorage` every rendering. This behavior causes a performance issue due to getting data multiple times. You can use `useEffect` to read data only once after the first rendering.

```
function Ebook() {
    const [ebookData, setEbookData] = React.useState([]);

    //only add data for the first rendering
    useEffect(() => {
      setEbookData(JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("ebook")));
    }, []);

    /*function that displays the specific text of a specific element onto the console*/
    const elementLogFunction = (ebook) =>{
        console.log(ebook.trackName)
    }


    return (
        <section id="musicRender">
           {ebookData.results.map((ebook, i)=>{
               return (
               <div key={i} className='ebookContentContainer'>
                   <div className="ebookPicture">
                   <img src={ebook.artworkUrl100} alt={ebook.trackName} />
                   </div>
                   
                   <div className="ebook-description">
                       <p className="ebookAuthor">Author: {ebook.artistName}</p>
                       <p ref={bookName} className='ebookAName'>Book Name: {ebook.trackName}</p>
                       <p className="price">Price: R{(ebook.price * 15.36).toFixed(0)}</p>
                   <button onClick={() => elementLogFunction(ebook)} className="favourites-btn">Add To Favourites</button>
                   </div>
               </div>)
            })}
        </section>
    )
  }

export default Ebook
```